# Unable to run Cloud Messaging for Android sample application on Android Studio

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Followed ,steps given on https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start ,but could not run successfully,giving below error while `compiling`.

```
Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 22.0.1
install.build.tools Install Build Tools 22.0.1 and sync project
```

Comment: Did you update to the latest build tools in the SDK Manager?